# Date checker is not working - false negative

Tags: java, date, conditional-statements

So I got an assignment to build a `Date` class. When I am receiving a day, month and a year as parameters, I need to make sure that the Date is valid. I do it by calling a function named `isDateValid`. According to the instructions, if the date is valid, the parameters will be set has the properties of the class, otherwise, I need to create the date with the default value of `1/1/2000`. however, when I run the testers the university has provided, it seems that even if the Date is valid, the actual Date will be set the default - meaning that the function `isDateValid` is returning false when it is supposed to return true.

Here is one of the objects created by the tester:

```
    Date d1 = new Date(3, 5, 1998);
```

, when I run it, I get the default date.

the function is:

```java
 private boolean isDateValid(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        return  (((month == JANUARY || month == MARCH || month == JULY || month == AUGUST || month == OCTOBER || month == DECEMBER || month == MAY) && 
        day <= DAYS_IN_JAN_MAR_MAY_JUL_AUG_OCT_DEC) ||
            ((month == APRIL || month == JUNE || month == SEPTEMBER || month == NOVEMBER) && day <= DAYS_IN_JUN_APR_SEP_NOV) ||
            (((month == FEBRUARY && day <= DAYS_IN_FEB_LEAP)) || (isLeapYear(year) && day <= DAYS_IN_FEB_NO_LEAP && month == FEBRUARY)) ) &&
        ( day >= MINIMUM_DAY  && month >= MINIMUM_MONTH && month <= MAXIMUM_MONTH && year >= MINIMUM_YEAR && year <= MAXIMUM_YEAR);
    }
```

Here are the contants being used:

```java
    private final int MINIMUM_YEAR = 1000;
    private final int MINIMUM_MONTH = 1;
    private final int MINIMUM_DAY = 1;
    private final int MAXIMUM_DAY = 31;
    private final int MAXIMUM_MONTH = 12;
    private final int MAXIMUM_YEAR = 9999;
    private final int JANUARY = 1;
    private final int FEBRUARY = 2;
    private final int MARCH = 3;
    private final int APRIL = 4;
    private final int MAY = 5;
    private final int JUNE = 6;
    private final int JULY = 7;
    private final int AUGUST = 8;
    private final int SEPTEMBER = 9;
    private final int OCTOBER = 10;
    private final int NOVEMBER = 11;
    private final int DECEMBER = 12;
    private final int DAYS_IN_JAN_MAR_MAY_JUL_AUG_OCT_DEC = 31;
    private final int DAYS_IN_JUN_APR_SEP_NOV = 30;
    private final int DAYS_IN_FEB_NO_LEAP = 28;
    private final int DAYS_IN_FEB_LEAP = 29;
```

Edit:

I got a comment suggesting that the source of the error can be somewhere else, so I will provide all related code to this function:

this is the function I use in order to determent whether or not it is a leap year

```java
    private static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        if (year % 4 != 0) {
            return false;
        } else if (year % 400 == 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (year % 100 == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and here is the constructor of the Date class:

```java
 public Date (int day, int month, int year)
    {
        if(isDateValid(day, month, year))
        {
            _day = day;
            _month = month;
            _year= year;         
        }
        else
        {
            _day = DEFULTE_DAY;
            _month = DEFULTE_MONTH;
            _year = DEFULTE_YEAR;
        }
    }
```

I really can't determent what is the problem, and the fact that it is one complex condition and not multiple if statements make it hard to debug.

Since it is an assignment I am not allowed to use "actual java" - the java date class etc...

Where did I was mistaken?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Returning a huge condition is not good practice because it makes it hard to debug. You should break it up into separate conditional statements inside the method and only return the result.

Comment: Just tested some cases - for most of them your `isDateValid` seems to work. Probably the real problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @ThomasKläger added possible code where the error can be located in.

Comment: Could it be that your university’s test software gives you the arguments in a different order, for example (year, month, day) or (month, day, year)?

Comment: @OleV.V. here is one of the objects created by the tester:  Date d1=new Date(3,5,1998);, when I run it, I get the default date

Comment: You have got a bug, though: `isDateValid(29, 2, 1999)` returns `true`. 1999 was not a leap year, so it should return `false`.

Comment: @Ole V.V. I think I got everything right, except the bug you told me about, why do you think it happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your `isDateValid` method with every valid date from year 1799 through 2100 and with every valid date in year 1000 and year 9999. It returns `true` every time. Also for the example date you gave, `isDateValid(3, 5, 1998)` returns true. So I believe that the cause for returning a default date doesn’t lie within the `isDateValid` method that you have posted. I can’t tell you where then, but you need to look elsewhere.

You have got a bug, though: `isDateValid(29, 2, 1999)` returns `true`. 1999 was not a leap year, so it should return false. So let’s examine the code dealing with February:

```
    ((month == FEBRUARY && day <= DAYS_IN_FEB_LEAP))
         || (isLeapYear(year) && day <= DAYS_IN_FEB_NO_LEAP && month == FEBRUARY)
```

(I have broken it over two lines to fit it better into Stack Overflow.) In case of 29th February in a leap year, the first line evaluates to true. Since there is `||` (logical or) between the two lines, `true` is the result of the entire expression. Java uses lazy evaluation here and doesn’t even evaluate the second line, but even if it did, the result of the *logical or* operation would still be `true`.

You could probably find a way to fix it, but you shouldn’t. Instead rewrite your entire method along the lines in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you've sort of identified, that return statement is hard to debug. I'd break it up into manageable sections.

```
private boolean isDateValid(int day, int month, int year) {
    bool retVal = true;
    retVal = retVal && (month >= JANUARY) && (month <= DECEMBER);
    retVal = retVal && (day >= 1) && (day <= DAYS_IN_JAN_MAR_MAY_JUL_AUG_OCT_DEC);
    if (month == APRIL || month == JUNE ...) {
        retVal = retVal && (day < DAYS_IN_JUN_APR_SEP_NOV);
    }

    if (month == FEBRUARY) {
         .. handle the complex case of February
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Note also that because January through December are values in the range [1..12] without gaps, you don't need to check month against each value but can just check within January..December. That makes this a little simpler.

That weird-ass complicated return statement is just begging for something problematic. It's too easy to get something that complicated wrong.

Comment: I get the basic idea but I am surely missing something important that causes the error. It would be great if you can provide the full code